# Drop Function and Labels

Tags: python, pandas

I'm writing code to randomly select people for a "lottery" drawing. Each person can be entered into the lottery multiple times; however, they can only be drawn once. The program will operate as a loop that runs X number of times. It'll select a person, append them to the variable "lucky winner" and then drop them from the dataframe so that they cannot be selected the next time the loop runs.

```
import pandas as pd

dataframe = pd.read_csv(r'csv file', header=None, delimiter=',')
    
lucky_winners = []

i=0
while i < 10:
    lucky_winner = dataframe.sample(n=1)
    lucky_winners.append(lucky_winner)
    dataframe = dataframe.drop(lucky_winner[0].index) 
    i+=1
```

I have two issues 1) the drop function isn't working and 2) The winner could potentially be selected twice if all rows with the same label aren't dropped. How do I write the drop function so that it drops based on label and not index?

Thanks all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ended up going with this:

```
df= pd.read_csv(r'csv file', header=None, delimiter=',')
lucky_winner = df.sample(n=8,weights='weight')
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of looping and dropping from DataFrame, use weighted random:

```
import numpy as np

people = list('ABCD')
entries = np.array([3, 3, 2, 1])
entries = entries / entries.sum()

# Select 3 random winners from list above
winners = np.random.choice(people, 3, replace=False, p=entries)
```

Comment: Thanks! I ended up using something a little bit different:                                                                                                               df= pd.read_csv(r'csv file', header=None, delimiter=',')                                                       winners = df.sample(n=8,weights='weight')